# Whats about SIGAR jar and how it is used in the application?

Tags: java, sigar

i want to developed one web application where
using SIGAR jar concept to fetch the information
about the network machine just like a monitoring on network application.
but i don't know more about SIGAR
plz any body help me to understand about SIGAR
and is really the SIGAR can fetch the information
about machine in the network.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Sigar API in one of my applications to gather information about Java processes running on it. Its really useful and provides accurate and useful information. It is also well documented and easy to use.
Here's the documentation link : http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/

Have a look at the classes in the documentation to see if they provide the information you're looking for.

Its ProcessTableQueryLanguage (PTQL) is extremely useful for gathering information, especially on the basis of PIDs. Here's the PTQL guide link : http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/PTQL

And the download link : http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/

Comment: Unfortunately, that documentation link is broken. Here's a link from perl.org: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOUGM/hyperic-sigar-1.6.3-src/docs/javadoc/index.html